# String includes with two statements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form where one can enter info gain if the want to change anything. The data is taking from the API, this.company is JSON and this.company.name points to the company name.

I have a if else code that does something if the string starts with Be or Pe, first though I want to do something when it doesn't include any of those. But I can't seem to make it with two statements. Can't find any documentation on this what so ever.

Entire code is just two more if else based if it's Be or Pe. They do not affect this code, that works when company name matches any of those. Problem is when company name does not match any of those.

Can anyone help me out?

Tried this:

```
if (!this.company.name.includes("Be") || !this.company.name.includes("Pe")){
do something}
```

Also tried

```
if ((!this.company.name.includes("Be") || !this.company.name.includes("Pe"))){
do something}
```

Can't get it to work. Last resort is to change the if else and make a last else that will be fall back. But that will cause another problem when input isn't done at all.

Edit.

Seems I wasn't clear on the agenda and full code. I wanted to see if it's possible to have two statements, and use ! infront of them. Here's the full code.

```
if (this.company){
  if (!this.company.name.includes("Be") || !this.company.name.includes("Pe")){
    this.category = 0;
    some code which will eliminate further questions in the form..
  } 
  else if (this.company.name.includes("Be"){
    this.category = 1;
    some code ...
  } 
  else if (this.company.name.includes("Pe"){
    this.category = 2;
    some code...
  }
}
```

Comment: To check if a string starts with a specific string you should use startsWith instead of includes

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing? Because `BeFoo` will fail `!.includes("Be")` but succeed on the `!.includes("Pe")`, so the OR is `true`. Not sure what behaviour you expect.

Comment: @Olli Edited that to my answer. Cheers.

Comment: Your condition will always return true. Just use '&&' instead;

Comment: Thanks for input. I updated the code. I only want to do something if it does not include 'Be' or 'Pe'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a minor logic problem here.
I think you wanna go for something like:

```
if (this.company.name && !(this.company.name.includes("Be") || this.company.name.includes("Pe"))){
```

That means when the company has a name and this name has no "Be" or "Pe" in the name. Remember if you wanna negate a statement you really have to negate the whole statement and not only parts of it or partwise.

```
(!A || !B) is not equal to !(A || B)
```

The first one means When A or B doesnt include "Be" and "Pe" - so far so good - but this statement is also true when **only** A doesn't include "Be" independent from what B is and it's also true when **only** B doesn't include "Pe" independent from A. On the upperhand the second one spoken means when A or B doesn't include "Be" and "Pe" - nothing else - You could also write something like `(!A && !B)` this is the same like `!(A || B)`.

That means you could also go with:

```
if(!this.company.name.includes("Be") && !this.company.name.includes("Pe"))
```

A general mathematical overview about this topic would be "[Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)".

Further you said when the name starts with "Be" or "Pe" in your suggestion with `"include"` these search strings can be anywhere in the String not only in the beginning.

The solution would be the [startsWith](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) method for strings:
`this.company.name.startsWith("Pe")`

> Regarding to your update

Correct me if im wrong but I think "be" and "pe" is just the beginning and more categories planned.

Under this conditions i would think of something like this:

```
 if (this.company)
    switch(this.company.name.slice(0,2)){
     case "Be": this.category = 2;break;
     case "Pe": this.category = 1;break;
        //possibly more conditions
     default : this.category = 0;break; //when company name doesn't start with the cases before
    }
```

In my personal point of view this is a bit more readable. But this depends on the amount of methods and things you wanna call if the conditions are true.

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna try this and see if it help. Updated the code as well incase that helps.

Comment: Glad i could help! :- )

Comment: `!(A || B)` is equal to `!A && !B` according to [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). I personally find the latter more readable since it removes the brackets.

Comment: Right! Both are logically the same. Personally I also prefer the spelling with the double and sign &&. But I think it points out clearer where the mistake was - When you have any statement like (A OR B) and want that A OR B shouldn't include the String - you have to negate the whole statement and not each part. Which resulted in the unwanted behaviour. But thanks for pointing it out I will add that to my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Just add an initial if/else statement to check if there is an input value or not and within the if statement, you can nest your second if/else statement for checking if the company name starts with "Be" or "Pe" using the [startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method.

```
if (this.company.name) { // checks if input has value or not
    if (this.company.name.startsWith("Be") || this.company.name.startsWith("Pe")) {
        [do something]
    } else {
        [no company which starts with Be or Pe. Do something else]
    }
} else {
    [no value was inputted. do something else]
}
```

### Edit:

With regards to your updated question, you can just add a bang `!` in the nested if statement and add the other if statements as required like this:

```
    if (this.company.name) { // checks if input has value or not
        if (!this.company.name.startsWith("Be") && !this.company.name.startsWith("Pe"))) {
            this.category = 0;
        } else
        if (this.company.name.startsWith("Be")) {
            this.category = 1;
        } else
        if (this.company.name.startsWith("Pe")) {
          this.category = 2;
        }
    } else {
        [no value was inputted. do something else]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code. Perhaps that helps in understanding what I want to do.

Comment: I really like that solution, but I think I decided to skip startsWith for some reason, not sure if it was performance. But I'm gonna try both solutions I got and see which fits best. Big thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp.test`

```
if(/^(?:Pe|Be)/.test(this.company.name)) {
    //starts with Pe or Be
} else {

}
```

If only care about the case when `name` does not include any of these

```
    if(/^(?!Pe|Be)/.test(this.company.name)) {
      //does not start with Pe or Be
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, will look into it.